# nodejs write raw image data to jpeg file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, fs

I am getting data from a get request. The data (in the body of the response) looks something like this:

```
... ÿÀ���"�ÿÄ��������������ÿÄ�N��!1"AQa2q¡#BR±ð3brS²ÁÂÑá$ñCDTst¢³&45dÃÒÿÄ������������ÿÄ�-������!1A"Qa¡ðq±ÁÑ2áÿÚ���?�û." """ """ """ """ """ """ """ """ """ """ """ """ """ """ """ """ """ """ """ """ """ """ """ """R1º#ª¥7Jíî½M6îNö ]·!]=Fv­ß`7~qÆee²%·JokkZüCbìþ<ù{ã9öùË®´(%A,Ià�2I?t×bn6wÆù¥V 2SÀ><k5ºÙØ92EhÎçü¨/aÝ!ã|ñþ¥ñßT}U«¦ÒÚµ«xuÕfÆ³ KØ {ù{ð$·DúBMZÆcp}´R|Mä2ó8üg)·ùôfõ$zXiRÞü}óÆ>,êÚûíR5ý:\ .....
```

the response headers look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 26965
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: image/jpeg; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 06 Feb 2012 21:14:21 GMT
Expires: Mon, 06 Feb 2012 22:14:21 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600
Last-Modified: Fri, 13 Feb 2009 23:31:30 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: Dropta Server 1.0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
```

I want to get the body content which is my image data and save it to a `name.jpeg` file on the server.

How can I do that? I tried using buffers combined with the `fs` module, but I am kind of lost.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's an example, which downloads http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Jagdschloss_Granitz_4.jpg to `name.jpeg`

```
var fs=require('fs');
var http=require('http');

var f=fs.createWriteStream('name.jpeg');

var options={
    host:'upload.wikimedia.org',
    port:80,
    path:'/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Jagdschloss_Granitz_4.jpg'
}

http.get(options,function(res){
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        f.write(chunk);
    });
    res.on('end',function(){
        f.end();
    });
});
```

Comment: So can I have multiple streams open at the same time? I would like to write multiple images to disk at the same time, but when I tried to put this in a loop it went a bit crazy and crashed. So if I do an image at the time it works. Can I have multiple streams running at the same time?

Comment: This doesnt answer the question. How do save the response data directly without creating an additional request if you already have the response body/text?

Comment: @stewe `res.on('end'` can sometimes fire before `f.write` is finished and thus prematurely end writeStream before the image is fully written

Answer (score 9):

A slightly shorter version, which uses [Stream.pipe](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipe_destination_options):

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    imgSource = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Jagdschloss_Granitz_4.jpg';

http.get(imgSource, function(res) {
  res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('wiki.jpg'));
});
```

Comment: for me this is a better answer than the one accepted