# JPEG File Encoding and writeFile in Node JS

Tags: node.js, encoding, request

I'm using `http.request` to download JPEG file. I am then using `fs.writeFile` to try to write the JPEG file out to the hard drive.

None of my JPEG files can be opened, they all show an error (but they do have a file size). I have tried all of the different encodings with `fs.writeFile`.

What am I messing up in this process?

Here's what the working one is showing when viewing it raw:
[image]

And here is what the bad one using fs.writeFile is showing:
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [nodejs write raw image data to jpeg file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168182/nodejs-write-raw-image-data-to-jpeg-file)

Comment: I'm trying to get fs.writeFile to work, those other answers to not address this

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to write to the disk? While `.setEncoding` may solve your problem, there is likely a better way because that encoding is not recommended in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, needed to use `res.setEncoding('binary');` on my `http.request`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, looking to the previous response, I was able to save de media correctly:

```
fs.writeFile(
    filepath + fileName + extension,
    mediaReceived, // to use with writeFile       
    { encoding: "binary" }, // to use with writeFile ***************WORKING
    (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("An error ocurred while writing the media file.");
        return console.log(err);
      }
    }
  );
```